# What is wrong with my ajax call to php file in data section?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I am able to get my php value into javascript variable but I don't think my script.js is finding it. There  of course are alot of files missing for the sake of keeping this question clean but my problem is that script.js get `schoolId` as `undefined` instead of the actual value but when I console.log schoolId i get a value of "1"(first page has id 1 so that works).

Header.php :

```
<?php 
//gets current page id
$schoolOfficialId = $specificSchool[0]["id"]; 
?>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id='schoolOfficialId' value="<?php echo $schoolOfficialId;?>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();
    </script>
</body>
```

script.js: ajax call here NOTE: in the ajax i know the data is having trouble finding schoolId from the header.php to send to php file.

```
// execute an ajax query to push id of page to load_more.php
            $.ajax({
                url: 'load_more.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {schoolId:schoolId},
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("working");
                }
            });
```

my load_more.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['schoolId'])) {
    echo "yes";
}else {
    echo "nope";
}//keeps echoing nope because the schoolId is not received
```

Comment: How and where is that javascript included?

Comment: You need to load the script after `schoolId` is declared, or declare it in the script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the script running before the declaration.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>` is in head, but `var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();` is at the bottom of the page.

Include the script after declaring schoolId.

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id='schoolOfficialId' value="<?php echo $schoolOfficialId;?>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

P.S. despite other answers, `data: {schoolId:schoolId},` is perfectly fine unless the keyname conflicts with a reserved word.

Comment: Ok I did that and my console.log says working but still I cant get the scriptId to get to the load_more.php. That is the issue right now. script.js is its own file while load_more.php is its own file as well. I would think that my php script works but it keeps outputting "nope";

Comment: nevermind I fixed it. In my script.js i had a syntax error so the whole thing would not run but you are right. I put the script after the schoolId and it worked. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Load ajax code after defining `var schoolId` and also check source code whether php printing value for `schoolId` correctly or not and also do not forget to use `$(document).ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();

$.ajax({
            url: 'load_more.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {schoolId:schoolId},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
})
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
if (isset($_POST['schoolId'])) {
echo $_POST['schoolId'];
}else {
echo "nope";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By running the following i can see yes in alert ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>stackoverflow</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var schoolId = $("#schoolOfficialId").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {schoolId: schoolId},
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ajax file (ajax.php) :

```
if (isset($_POST['schoolId'])) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "nope";
}
```

Comment: Ok I did that and my console.log says working but still I cant get the scriptId to get to the load_more.php. That is the issue right now is that  script.js is its own file while load_more.php is its own file as well. I would think that my script.js file can pick up schoolId but it does not that is why my load_more.php says nope. How can I push that variable schoolId into script.js?

Comment: I have updated the code. now you can see how to catch the schoolId.